# How to return to edit form?

Tags: joomla

I have this code in my controller (admin):

```
function save(){
        $model = $this->getModel('mymodel');

        if ($model->store($post)) {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Yes!' );
        } else {
            $msg = JText::_( 'Error :(' );
        }
        $link = 'index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview';
        $this->setRedirect($link, $msg);
}
```

In model I have:

```
function store(){
        $row =& $this->getTable();

        $data = JRequest::get('post');
        if(strlen($data['fl'])!=0){
            return false;
        }

        [...]
```

And this is working - generate error message, but it return to items list view. I want to stay in edit view with entered data. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your controller you can:

```
if ($model->store($post)) {
   $msg = JText::_( 'Yes!' );
} else {
    // stores the data in your session
    $app->setUserState('com_mycomponent.edit.mymodel.data', $validData);

    // Redirect to the edit view
    $msg = JText::_( 'Error :(' );
    $this->setError('Save failed', $model->getError()));
    $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');
    $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&id=XX'), false));
}
```

then, you will need to load the data from session with something like:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_mycomponent.edit.mymodel.data', array());
```

normally this is loaded in the method "loadFormData" in your model. Where to load that data will depend on how are you implementing your component. If you are using the Joomla's form api then you can add the following method to your model.

```
protected function loadFormData()
{
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_mycomponent.edit.mymodel.data', array());

    if (empty($data)) {
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

EDIT:

BUT please note, that Joomla's API already can do all this for you if you controller inherits from "JControllerForm", you don't need to rewrite the save method. The best way to create your component is copying what is in Joomla's core components, com_content for example

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to rewrite `save` or any method.

If you really want to override something and want to update something before or after save, you should use `JTable` file.

For Example:

```
/**
 * Example table
 */
class HelloworldTableExample extends JTable
{
    /**
     * Method to store a node in the database table.
     *
     * @param   boolean  $updateNulls  True to update fields even if they are null.
     *
     * @return  boolean  True on success.
     */
    public function store($updateNulls = false)
    {
        // This change is before save
        $this->name = str_replace(' ', '_', $this->name);

        if (!parent::store($updateNulls))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // This function will be called after saving table
        AnotherClass::functionIsCallingAfterSaving();
    }
}
```

You can extends any method using JTable class and that's the recommended way to doing it.